# How do jQuery objects imitate arrays?

Tags: javascript, jquery

jQuery objects act like arrays without polluting native prototypes.
How is this achieved?

I know it's not just objects with numeric keys - so perhaps it's just a matter of providing the respective methods (something like `jQuery.prototype.indexOf = Array.prototype.indexOf`).

I've googled and looked at the source, but couldn't find a definitive answer.

Comment: What makes you believe it's not just objects with numeric keys?

Comment: For one thing, Firebug displays jQuery objects as arrays, but not such manually created objects - and I doubt it has special handling for jQuery.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Although jQuery objects act like arrays, they are actually only *array-like* objects. An array-like object is an object using numeric keys and having a `length` property - that is the minimum needed for compatibility with the [native array methods](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array#Methods).

Because jQuery objects are only array-like and not actual `Array` objects, native array operations (like [`indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) or [`reverse`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reverse)) cannot be called directly. You can use `Array.prototype` though, or extend jQuery's functionality.

```
$('div').reverse(); // TypeError: $("div").reverse is not a function

// we can use Array.prototype though
Array.prototype.reverse.apply($('div'));

// or we can extend jQuery very easily
$.fn.reverse = Array.prototype.reverse;
$('div').reverse(); // now it works!
```

You are correct in your assumption that Firebug does not include any special-casing for formatting jQuery objects. A quick search reveals [a relevant post](http://www.mail-archive.com/firebug@googlegroups.com/msg01548.html) on the Firebug mailing list. Assuming the information is still correct (the post is from January) Firebug will format an object as an array if it has a **finite length** and a **`splice` method**.

JQuery fulfils both of these criteria, but [their implementation of `splice`](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/fef476def30f4b1f3cfa902fff11bb761ab6ecfd/src/core.js#L273) is nothing more than a direct copy of the native `Array` method. It is undocumented, which means it's either only for internal use, or perhaps added solely for the purpose of tricking Firebug into formatting jQuery objects nicely.

Comment: This is excellent - thanks!
I'd hesitate to add a splice method just to make it look pretty in Firebug, but that's just a minor detail. (PS: There's a typo in your post; you mention "slice" instead of "splice".)

Comment: Thank you - corrected. I only suggest that the `splice` method was added to jQuery specifically for Firebug because jQuery's 1.2 branch does _not_ expose such a method. Indeed, I do remember a short period of time in which my jQuery objects were not being formatted as `Arrays` in Firebug. Of course, the method's introduction in 1.3 may have just coincidence.

Comment: Thank you – this was interesting to chance upon. I note Safari’s web inspector seems to use the same criteria – `length` object and `splice` method – to format objects as arrays: `var o; o = { length: 2, splice: function(x) { } };` => `[ ]` (tho’ firebug rigorously prints: `[undefined, undefined]`).

Answer (score 5):

Look in jquery code (development), line 139:

```
// Force the current matched set of elements to become
// the specified array of elements (destroying the stack in the process)
// You should use pushStack() in order to do this, but maintain the stack
setArray: function( elems ) {
    // Resetting the length to 0, then using the native Array push
    // is a super-fast way to populate an object with array-like properties
    this.length = 0;
    Array.prototype.push.apply( this, elems );
        return this;
},
```

This is because any result of jquery queries is array.

Comment: Thanks. I'd seen this as well, but it doesn't seem to suffice:

var MyObj = function(args) {
    this.length = 0;
    Array.prototype.push.apply(this, arguments);
    return this;
};

var obj = new MyObj("hello", "world");

Comment: Don't return `this` from a constructor! Also, `var` sets a variable, but it does not return a value; if you are executing that snippet in a Firebug-like tool: `var MyObj = function(args) { this.length = 0; Array.prototype.push.apply(this, arguments); }; obj = new MyObj("hello", "world");`

Comment: I'm confused: If it's not a constructor, "this" won't be the object (just window) though!? Can you provide a working sample?

Comment: `MyObj` _is_ a constructor, that's the point! And that is a working sample :)

Comment: Sorry, I misread your earlier statement.
However, your code there doesn't seem to work for me: obj.indexOf is undefined - also, obj is not being displayed as an array in Firebug. Am I missing something?

Comment: I will post an answer explaining Firebug's behaviour, give me a few minutes.