# .find and .contents not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a condition if my parent `div` has children with class `.ads` then it should `alert('true')` else `alert('false')`. But my function returns `true` in both cases. Here is jsFiddle link http://jsfiddle.net/F3EXf/

```
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.7.2.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function(){
            if($('#me').find('.ads')){
                alert('true')
            } else {
                alert('false')
            }
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="me">
        <div class="noads">aaaa</div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Hi vega Please see below screenshot

[image]

Comment: because in your example there is no ads class... there is a "noads" class though.

Comment: yes you are right, but it should return false

Comment: Only if you check the selectors length. Selecting the wrong element does not trigger an error in jQuery, it just fails  silently.

Comment: like others said, check "length"

Comment: But why it is return true, what is the reason behind

Comment: You can always just do `alert($('#me').find('.ads').length!==0);`

Comment: But why it is returns true without using .length method

Comment: Even an empty jQuery object still exists *as* an object, so it will always evaluate to `true`. However it's length is zero, so `$emptyObject.length` will evaluate to `false`. http://jsfiddle.net/mblase75/F3EXf/2/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To check if an element exists use instead

```
if ($('#me').find('.ads').length) {
   ...
}
```

Since `$('#me').find('.ads')` will always return true (it returns a jQuery-wrapped empty object evaluated as a true value) even if the element targeted by `find()` doesn't exist

Comment: can you elaborate it more. why it is return true in all case

Comment: because `.find()` method allows us to search through the descendants of these elements in the DOM tree and construct a new jQuery object from the matching elements.

Comment: `find()` creates a jQuery wrapped node collection, evaluated as true in any case. What matters for your purpose is to check if that collection is empty or not

Comment: @fabrizio: I want to learn more about jQuery wrapped node collection. Can your refer me any article or something related to jQuery wrapped node

Answer (score 3):

All jQuery [**selectors**](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/) and [**traversing**](http://api.jquery.com/category/traversing/) functions returns a jQuery object. jQuery object is an Array-Like object that has properties and reference to core functions.

A small example to show the list of properties and functions readily available in jQuery object http://jsfiddle.net/Tj9e8/1/

When you call the jQuery function as `$(selector)`, It creates a jQuery object with wrapped list of matched element(s) based on the selector.

For example: When you do `$('#test')`, it creates a jQuery object and wraps DOM element with ID `test`.

Check the below code snippet from jQuery's `.init` function for handling for ID selector

```
elem = document.getElementById(match[2]); 
//match[2] is string 'test' in '#test' that was passed to $('#test')

if (elem && elem.parentNode) {
   if (elem.id !== match[2]) {
      return rootjQuery.find(selector);
   }
   //below 2 lines allows the jQuery object to behave like array like objects
   this.length = 1;
   this[0] = elem; //elem is nothing but the dom node.
}
this.context = document;
this.selector = selector;
return this; //Returns jQuery object
```

[For more information check out the `.init` function code](http://james.padolsey.com/jquery/#v=git&fn=init)

Below is the snapshot of the `$('#test')`.

[image]

As you can see the length is 0 but even still the $ function return jQuery object with length 0. This is to protect the next chained call instead of throwing an error.

In most cases, we select an element to run some function on it..

**Ex:** `$('#test').addClass('example')`.

1. Call's jQuery function using `$('#test')` with a string arguement `'#test'`
2. jQuery call's `.init` above to determine the type of the argument and returns a jQuery object wrapped with matched elements(if any, else just jQuery object).
3. Call `.addClass` on jQuery object, which internally iterate overs the list of matched elements and adds the class to the element. Below is snippet from `.addClass` function code

   ```
   if (value && typeof value === "string") {
       classNames = value.split(core_rspace);
       for (i = 0, l = this.length; i < l; i++) { 
       //^-- This is where it iterate over matched elements
           elem = this[i];
           if (elem.nodeType === 1) {
   ```

Now the points to note is,

1. $ function always returns a jQuery object
2. The jQuery object is nothing but a javascript object with the following

   a. Wrapped set of matched elements [An example using .find](http://jsfiddle.net/Tj9e8/4/)

   b. properties   - [Sample that lists properties](http://jsfiddle.net/Tj9e8/2/)

   c. functions    - [Sample that lists functions](http://jsfiddle.net/Tj9e8/3/)

**HTML:**

```
<ul>
    <li>Test</li>
    <li class="red">Test</li>
    <li>Test</li>
    <li class="red">Test</li>
</ul>
```

**JS:**

```
var $lisample = $('ul').find('.red');
```

Not the wrapped set of matched elements as a result of `.find` looks like below,

[image]

### More reading

1. [How do jQuery objects imitate arrays?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1483445/how-do-jquery-objects-imitate-arrays)
2. [jQuery object and DOM element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6974582/jquery-object-and-dom-element)
3. http://blog.buymeasoda.com/does-calling-the-jquery-function-return-an-ob

Comment: thanks for explaining it very clearly. you have posted screenshot with DOM. I want to check length of my selector so how to check this in DOM. Like you do

Comment: I am searching .sub class in DOM, function work perfectly. but when i am looking in DOM it is showing its length 0. here is http://jsfiddle.net/rRNkb/. i am attaching DOM screenshot in my question

Comment: @amit Did you see the snapshot.. the selector was `""`.. I am not able to replicate the issue that you mentioned.. and your fiddle works fine.. except for that missing `</div>` tag.

Comment: Thanks for reply, i just want to know how to see length of selector in DOM

Comment: @amit `$(selector).length` will return you the length of the selector(meaning matched elements count).. if that is what you want.. If not, please post and example and tell me what you expect and what was returned..

Comment: I understand you answer, You post snapshot where you highlight length of "li.red" I want to know how to access to that tool.

Comment: @amit It just a break point in the firebug. [setting break-point in firebug](https://getfirebug.com/doc/breakpoints/demo.html). After it stops at the breakpoint, check the Watch and inspect the selector variable.

Comment: Thanks a lot for you nice and valuable effort

Answer (score 1):

```
 $(function () {
        if ($('#me').find('.ads').length>0) {
            alert('true');
        } else {
            alert('false');
        }
    });
```

Comment: No need for the `> 0` because 0 = false and everything above will be seen as true.

Answer (score 1):

I usually do this:

```
if(typeof variable != 'undefined')
```

so in your case:

```
if(typeof variable[0] != 'undefined'){
```

because [.find](http://api.jquery.com/find/) function returns an array.

**CODE**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $(function(){
                var variable = $('#me').find('.ads');
                if(typeof variable[0] != 'undefined'){
                    alert('true')
                } else {
                    alert('false')
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="me">
        <div class="noads">aaaa</div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

You can find info about `typeof variable != 'undefined'` [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1485840/whether-a-variable-is-undefined).

Answer (score 0):

Fiddle link: http://jsfiddle.net/F3EXf/8/

1.If you need to look for an element's children, use Children() straight away.
2.Also, try counting the elements that are resulted from your selector and then decide if         its available

```
$(function(){
    var children = $('#me').children('.noads');
if(children.length > 0){
    alert('true')
    }

    else {
        alert('false')

        }
})
```

​

for Demo, look for the fiddle link provided above.

To answer your question, why it alerts as true if the element is not present.

1. It returns an empty array but not a null array... It means it has some information in the resulting object but length is 'zero' but actually it is not null or undefined