# jQuery add not working with HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery

In the [jQuery `add` documentation](http://api.jquery.com/add/), it lists an `add(html)` overload which describes the `html` argument as:

> An HTML fragment to add to the set of matched elements.

Since there is already an `add(element)` overload, I assume this means that you pass it an HTML string, as in:

```
var set = $();
set.add("<div></div>");
document.write(set.length); // prints 0
```

However, [when this code is run](http://jsfiddle.net/s2zQr/), it has no effect on the jQuery wrapped set. What am I missing?

Comment: I doubt this is what you are looking for, but if you use the push method rather than the add method, it DOES result in a length of 1. May I ask what the purpose of this code is?

Comment: in that link just a few scrolls down it says this very clearly: 

"The following will not save the added elements, because the .add() method creates a new set and leaves the original set in pdiv unchanged:
12 
var pdiv = $("p");pdiv.add("div");  // WRONG, pdiv will not change"

Comment: @bobbybee: Do you know if `push` is part of the official jQuery API?

Comment: @cdmckay I doubt it. It's standard ECMAScript (what JS and AS3 are based off of), so probably JavaScript.

Comment: @bobbybee: It's standard ECMAScript for Arrays, not jQuery objects.  Anyway, I can't find it on the jQuery site, and this post discourages its use: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14524024/jquery-push-function

Comment: @cdmckay Ah, k. I spend much more time in Flash development that it just seems natural to write .push(obj) now :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You got to set the return of `add` to the `set` like below,

`set = set.add("<div></div>");`

`.add` returns the collated jQuery object which you can chain, it doesn't really add it to the original object.

Comment: Doh, rookie mistake. I forgot that it always returns a new set.

Answer (score 1):

It works fine if you define it in a single line: http://jsfiddle.net/s2zQr/3/

```
var set = $().add("<div></div>");
document.write(set.length);
```

as @Pavel Chernov noted... the .add() method creates a new set (and that's why your count never updated)

Answer (score 1):

> The following will not save the added elements, because the .add()
>   method creates a new set and leaves the original set in pdiv
>   unchanged:
>
> ```
> var pdiv = $("p");
> pdiv.add("div"); // WRONG, pdiv will not change
> ```

so your set is still empty