# jQuery.map errors when returning a map of object properties

Tags: javascript, jquery

In the following example:

HTML:

```
<ul>
  <li id="0"></li>
  <li id="213"></li>
  <li id="324"></li>
  <li id="764"></li>
</ul>
```

JS:

```
var map = $("ul").children().map(function(i, el) {
  return el.id;
});

console.log(Array.prototype.slice.call(map).join(":")); // 0:213:324:764 
console.log(map.join(":")); //error: Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function
```

The map function will error if trying to use native array methods,

if you parse the returned jq 'array' into a normal array - everything works.

What could be the reason to it?

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/hQZqU/1/

Comment: A jquery object is not an array and therefore doesn't have a `join` method. Call `.get()` first to convert the an array from the jquery object.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/ue2zc use `map.get().join(":")` @FelixKling comments pretty much sums up thing

Comment: thank you, but what baffles me is that the structure is array like, i,e: [val, val, val]. Is it possible to mimic such structure in JS without it being an array?

Comment: Seems to me like you should use `$.map` instead if you want an array and not a jQuery collection -> **http://jsfiddle.net/hQZqU/3/**

Comment: Yes. Every object that has numeric properties and a `.length` property is an array-like object. And thinking about it, since a jquery object usually contains DOM elements, what should happen when you concatenate them with a string?

Comment: More on array like objects here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1483445/how-do-jquery-objects-imitate-arrays

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your selector is a jQuery object (`$("ul").children()`), so `map` return this jQuery list of objects :

```
jQuery("0", "213", "324", "764")
```

In order to have an array, you have to use [`toArray`](http://api.jquery.com/toarray/) :

```
console.log(map.toArray().join(":"));
```

You can look at this fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/hQZqU/2/

Answer (score 0):

`.map()` will return jquery object but `.get()` on the result to work with a basic array.

```
var map = $("ul").children().map(function(i, el) {
    return el.id;
}).get();
```

**[jsfiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/nazmoonnoor/hQZqU/4/)**